# Twitter login for android and ios app in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter, air, adobe, flash-cs6

can any one tell me the proper steps to perform twitter login for android and ios app.Am working on flash CS6, Adobe AIR 18,and AS3. I want to do twitter login for mobile.And after login i want to take details of login-ed user like user id,email.How can i do that i searched in many forums but i did not get any answer.If anyone knows please tel me how to do that.I seen many ANE's but they are not working.I bought go-viral extension also but they given login to Facebook only.did not given login for twitter.

Comment: please give me any answer for this.is there any solution for this.@Gurtej Singh

Comment: Twitter uses OAuth to provide authentication. There are a number of OAuth libraries available to can be used to 'login' to Twitter and obtain a auth-token via their api (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview) but access to the user account information that you listed is not available (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

Comment: So finally there is no way to get twitter user details like userid,email in android and ios.@  RobertN

Comment: Read the API to see what is data is available via user profile: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public but it is not listed you would have to have the user enter the information you want.

Comment: Make your own ANE or get an existing one.